# Node.js beginner- request without query strings

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, query-string

I'm new to node.js. A project I'm working on requires that a large array (625 items) be stored in a MySQL database as a string and I'm using [Node MySQL](http://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) to accomplish that.

Right now I have it so that the row is updated when a request is made to "/(column name)?(value)". Unfortunately, it didn't take long to learn that passing 625 items as a string to node isn't the most efficient way of doing things.

Do you have any suggestions for alternate methods of passing a large array as a string besides querystrings?

```
var http = require('http'),
   mysql = require("mysql"),
   url = require("url"),
   express = require("express");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   user: "root",
   database: "ballot"

});  

var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.options('/', function (request, response)
{
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.end();
});

app.get('/', function (request, response)
{
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM pathfind;", function (error, rows, fields) {
        for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
        {
            response.send('<div id="layers">'+rows[i].layers+'</div> \
                            <div         id="speed">'+rows[i].speed+'</div> \
                            <div     id="direction">'+rows[i].direction+'</div>');
        }
        response.end();
    });
});

app.post('/', function (request, response)
{   
    console.log(request.param('data', null));
    var urlData = url.parse(request.url, true);
    if(urlData.pathname = '/layers')
    {
        col = "layers";
    }
    else if(urlData.pathname = '/speed')
    {
        col = "speed";
    }
else if(urlData.pathname = '/direction')
    {
        col = "direction";
    }
    req.addListener("data", function(data) {
        connection.query("UPDATE pathfind SET "+col+"="+data+" WHERE num=0",     function (error, rows, fields) {
            if (error)
            {
                app.close();
            }
        }); 
    });
});

app.listen(8080);**
```

EDIT: So now I know I need to use posts. I've rewritten the above code using express.js. Most examples that I look at online use posts with HTML forms, which is fine, but my project needs to post data via an AJAX request. Can someone show me how that data is parsed in node.js?

Comment: larger volumes of data are best sent via POST request, especially if that request results in modifications to the DB, as GET request is intended to be run any number of times without changing the state

Comment: So clearly I've been going about this the wrong way. How can I post the data to the database? I'm using jQuery's built-in ajax library, by the way.

Comment: use `Express`, instead of just `http` module, it has nice piece of middleware called bodyparser, which will give you access to the body of POST request. On client side use standard `jQuery.post(url, data, callback)` to post data.

Comment: How can I access the data with request.param(); if data isn't being posted through an HTML form?

Comment: @J4G A `POST` sent via form and via jQuery produce the same data.

Comment: your data will be posted as post request body, so you can access it via `req.body`, more detail here: http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body

Comment: Thanks ArtDeineka for all of your help. If you make an answer I'll select it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract post data like this.

```
if (req.method == 'POST') {
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        var postData = body.toString();
        console.log(postData);
    });
}
```